# В системе аутентификации не доступны роуты

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте!

После команды 
php artisan make:auth
генерируются необходимые шаблоны, роуты и контроллер HomeController

После команды
php artisan route:list
список доступных роутов отсутствует, вместо него

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in
   the script

Аутентификация работала нормально, потом что-то произошло (namespace ни в одном файле никуда не перемещал) ???

Спасибо!

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Namespace declaration  ....  Ошибка говорит о том что Namespace надо декларировать в самом начале файла.Посмотрите что там перед ним стоит,может пробел какой

Comment: Вы мне помогли, - спасибо!
По какой-то причине начало файла <?php контроллера AuthController оказалось смещенным на одну табуляцию - для проблемы этого оказалось достаточно!
Оформите, как ответ, - поставлю причку ))!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Namespace
>   declaration ....

Ошибка говорит о том что `Namespace` надо декларировать в самом начале файла.Посмотрите что там перед ним стоит,может пробел какой.